# Pandas Dataframe multiple rows with same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict = {
  "A": [1,2,3],
  "B": [4]
}
```

when I try to create a panda Dataframe I use:

`output_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index')`

Output:

| - | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 4 |  |  |

What I want:

| - | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df.stack().swaplevel(0,1)
```

---

```
1  A    1.0
2  A    2.0
3  A    3.0
1  B    4.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df.stack().swaplevel(0,1).reset_index(level=[1], name='a').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    level_1   a
0   A         1.0
1   A         2.0
2   A         3.0
3   B         4.0
```